# jquery mask for money range

Tags: jquery, maskedinput, jquery-mask

My User will input salary range
I want to format it so I use mask
But I want to mask my User input value like this

```
5 000 TL-8 000 TL
```

maybe my user input `1000 TL-100000 TL`

I tried this

```
$("#WageRange").mask("99999 TL - 99999 TL");
```

but this not work very well,it is less

and if user don't click enter it does not add TL to end
sometimes it give that result `8000TL-9000` (it should do this `8 000 TL -9 000 TL`)

I don't want use any third party plugin

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#WageRange").mask("0000TL - 0000r", {
      translation: {
        'r': {
          pattern: /[0-9]TL/,
          fallback: 'TL'
        }
      }
    });


This should work.
```

Comment: this is good but if I want to add 5TL-1000TL it does not work...It required 4 number

Comment: So, you want to add any number of characters but at the end it should have TL? Then instead of using mask,try js.

Comment: ı just want to numbers and want to add TL to end....   such example 50000TL-1TL  or 4000TL-7000TL with your sample I can not make this 4TL-400000TL

Comment: Yes, I think using mask we cannot achieve this. Because we have more than one combination.